# How to loop a code in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I have this Caesar's Cipher code in Python to encrypt some messages quickly, and show it to my classmates.

I have everything done, except something...

I want to make a 'Do you want to encrypt another message?' option, but I can't loop the code.

How can I loop the whole code? I'm using Python 3.5.1.

Here's my code:

```
print('QuantumShadow\'s Caesar Cipher')
message = input('Write your message here: ')
print('The encryption key is: ')
key = int(input())
print('Do you want to encrypt or decrypt?')
mode = input()
LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
translated = ''
message = message.upper()
for symbol in message:
    if symbol in LETTERS:
        num = LETTERS.find(symbol)
        if mode == 'encrypt':
            num = num + key
        elif mode == 'decrypt':
            num = num - key

        if num >= len(LETTERS):
            num = num - len(LETTERS)
        elif num < 0:
            num = num + len(LETTERS)
        translated = translated + LETTERS[num]
    else:
        translated = translated + symbol
    print(translated)
print('Do you want to encrypt\\decrypt another message?')
print('Here is where I want to make the loop')
print('Coded with Python by QuantumShadow.')
```

Comment: Put the code in the question, not in a link.  To make it a code block, highlight it and hit Ctrl-k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using a while loop that goes on forever (until you break out of it):

```
while True:
    # The rest of your code
    if not input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt another message [y/n]? ").lower().startswith("y"):
        break
print("Coded with Python by QuantumShadow.")
```

Comment: It is not too simple.  `Yes` would count as yes.  Try it.

Comment: @zondo I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to put the whole code inside a 'while running' loop, and in the end of the loop ask if the person wants to run the code again, if not, change running to False.

Before

```
print("Hello World!")
```

After

```
running = True
while running:
    print("Hello World!")
    answer = input("Would you like to run again? (y/N)")
    if answer != 'y':
        running = False
```

But the right way to do it would be to divide your code into functions, so the final result would be cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

After the print of the title line start the while loop

```
ask = True
while ask: # this was initialized to True
    message = input('Write your message here: ')
    key = int(input('The encryption key is: '))
    mode = input('Do you want to encrypt or decrypt?')

    # put the coding logic here
    next = input('Do you want to encrypt\\decrypt another message?')
    if next.lower() == 'no':
        ask = False
print('You have finished all messages')
```

Answer (score 0):

@APerson's solution works fine.  Try it out.

```
while True:
    print('QuantumShadow\'s Caesar Cipher')
    message = input('Write your message here: ')
    print('The encryption key is: ')
    key = int(input())
    print('Do you want to encrypt or decrypt?')
    mode = input()
    LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    translated = ''
    message = message.upper()
    for symbol in message:
        if symbol in LETTERS:
            num = LETTERS.find(symbol)
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num = num + key
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num = num - key

            if num >= len(LETTERS):
                num = num - len(LETTERS)
            elif num < 0:
                num = num + len(LETTERS)
            translated = translated + LETTERS[num]
        else:
            translated = translated + symbol
        print(translated)
    if input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt another message [yes/no]? ") != "yes":
        break
print("Coded with Python by QuantumShadow.")
```

Also consider moving `print(translated)` to outside of the for loop so the program only displays the final encrypted result.

Answer (score 0):

put this code above your code:

```
x=1
while x==1:
    Your Code after indent
    #Add the following lines below
    x=input("Press  to send another message or any other key to exit")
```

the above method is a simple one and needs little modification to your existing code. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
print('QuantumShadow\'s Caesar Cipher')
LETTERS = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

#Wrap your code
def get_message(): 
    message = input('Write your message here: (input q to quit)')
    if message == 'q':
        return message
    print('The encryption key is: ')
    key = int(input())
    print('Do you want to encrypt or decrypt?')
    mode = input()
    translated = '' 
    message = message.upper()  
    for symbol in message:
        if symbol in LETTERS:
            num = LETTERS.find(symbol)
            if mode == 'encrypt':
                num = num + key
            elif mode == 'decrypt':
                num = num - key

            if num >= len(LETTERS):
                num = num - len(LETTERS)
            elif num < 0:
                num = num + len(LETTERS)
            translated = translated + LETTERS[num]
        else:
            translated = translated + symbol
    return translated

#loop your code
while True:
    message = get_message()
    if message == 'q':
        break
    print (message)
```